# How to get DOM child elements from an already instantiated Angular Component inside the Component itself?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Let's say I have a component `<app-parent></app-parent>`. The file for it is `parent.component.ts`. I instantiate it inside `app.component.ts` with the following child element inside it:

```
<app-parent>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</app-parent>
```

My question is, how do i get the native element instance of `h1` **inside** `parent.component.ts`. The purpose I am searching for this functionality is to create a reusable table component, which you can add custom element columns inside of it, to allow a greater range of scenarios.

I have already seen some sort of this logic being implemented in Angular Material, specifically for `<mat-icon>`, where you can use it passing a text value **inside** the instantiated element itself, like so: `<mat-icon>refresh</mat-icon>`. Which in turn parses the content and places an svg icon in it's place.

Comment: You can create a directive or use a  ViewChild.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean classic `getElementsByTagName()` in javascript? You can indeed get elements like that and apply custom logic in your ts that will handle their template display. If you mean exactly something like `<mat-icon>refresh</mat-icon>`, then you'd need to make your own libraries or plugins. Much easier and closest to that, though, is to define your own components that will have selector you need and handle all the content and attributes as you like, for example: `<your-selector [icon]="thatSillyIconWithAnElephant"></your-selector>` and then with @Input grab the value and handle it in ts.